# Why does Visual Studio mark my added .cs files as "ignored"?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio

I cloned an existing but almost empty project on my local machine through GitHub for Windows. Then I opened it in VS 2017 and added a few classes after what they all became marked up as "ignored" with red icons with "minus" sign on them.

When I tried to make a commit, (I want to make commits and push through GitHub App), non of the files where pushed.

Then I tried right-clicking on the files and adding them to source control. Then "minus" signs became "+".

I also thought maybe the problem lies in the fact that I didn't stage them. So I did (in VS). But I still cannot push these files. After an attempt to make a commit in GitHub app all my .cs files again become marked up with "minus" sign.

What is the reason of it and how to make them not be signed as "ignored"?

Comment: I am having the same problem, have you managed to fix this?

Comment: Same issue in VS2015 ... TFS. I don't (think) I have .cs in any .tfignore file. I noticed issue many months ago ... just been living with it. Very annoying. Too easy to miss adding new files.

Comment: @ViniciusGualberto As far as I remember I ended up stopping to use the Github app for Windows and did the commits through the Visual Studio only (I don't think it's a good idea to try using them both and not sure there is a reason for it). So, as the answer on this question says "You need to add first,ensure they're staged,commit, then push". I am not sure but I guess that the problem was that I wasn't really familiar with how Git works and after staging the files in VS I had to make a commit in VS but I was making the commit in the GitHub app instead what I think doesn't makes any sence.

Answer (score 16):

They are (most likely) being ignored by .gitignore file.

If you can't see anything obvious (check substrings of the file name as well as extension), then look for these and remove them:

`/*
!/content/`

Comment: correct, a gulp function had ignored one of my json files, I manually deleted from .gitignore and now I have the green plus sign next to the file instead of a red minus.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this helps the @Tanya, and here's my partially similar experience.

And sadly (as a reflection on my powers of observation) it turned out to be exactly as @goamn had suggested.

I was building a new console app (very short list of files) to help me do a backup activity, and I had called the VS project “backup”.

What I missed (at first and second glance) was that in the .gitignore was the line (in the “Backup & report files” of all likely places!):

```
# Backup & report files from converting an old project file
# to a newer Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed,
# because we have git ;-)
Backup*
```

Merely removing this line from that file, even after I had (what appeared to me to be a horked) repository already set up and non functional in github, fixed it right up.  I was able to commit the files with no problem.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Say the `.gitignore` file has this:

```
*.log
```

in it.

Now, a project that's named with a `.Log` suffix will not be committed(for example a project called `CompanyName.Domain.Service.SubService.Log`)

To add such a project to source control, you'd need to manually add it using:

```
git add <RootFolder>/<CompanyName.Domain.Service.SubService>.Log/* -f
```

This will force commit the change contrary to the opinion of the `.gitignore` file. However, this does *not* remove the `.log` from the `.gitignore` file. But once the force commit happens, the project is already in source control and will therefore not be subject to the `.gitignore` file. Thereafter, commits to this project will be committed.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add first, ensure they're staged, commit, then push

Comment: In GitHub for Windows there is no stage option: I can only commit and then sync (push).

Comment: Have you checked your .gitignore on your git repo root folder? Make sure the folder name in which the igored files reside is not resolved in .gitignore, along with "*.cs" files et cetera

Comment: I don't think that the proplem is with the .gitignore because at the beginning we didn't even create a .gitignore file (what is a bad practice,  I know) and the proplem occurred even in that situation. Moreover, now when the .gitignore file is created the other members of the team don't have problems adding the same files to the same folfer and making a commit.